# When I upload data into an Sagemaker Notebook instance, in which directory does the data live and how do I access it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

You can add files to a Sagemaker notebook instance by using the "upload" button.  When you do this, to which directory are the files uploaded, and how can I view this in the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SageMaker Notebooks home is on `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker`

- Everything you send to `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker` will be visible in
  the Jupyter home page
- Everything you upload in the Jupyter home page
  will be visible in the terminal via `ls /home/ec2-user/SageMaker`
- The content of `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker` is persisted in a storage volume called the "ML Storage Volume", that is charged additionally to the
  instance compute pricing and defaults at 5GB. It can be up to 16TB in
  size. Content saved there stays persisted even when you switch off
  the notebook instance. On the other hand, anything you save anywhere
  else will be lost when you switch off the instance

Comment: On Sagemaker Studio my directory is like ```/home/sagemaker-user/myfolders/``` however I get an error when trying to change directories to here within my sagemaker notebook.